# Call JS function once hidden input has value from session attribute

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, session

How can I be able to automatically call a JS function once an assigned session attribute passes a value to a hidden input field in JSP. Kindly see below:

Java Class:

```
session.setAttribute("activity1", 1);
session.setAttribute("activity2", 0);
```

JSP:

```
<table id="activityTbl" style="width: 100%; border:1px solid black;" align="center">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Activity1</td>
        <td>Activity2</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="actDiv1" style="border:1px solid black;"></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="actDiv2" style="border:1px solid black;"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<input type="hidden" id="act1" value="${sessionScope.activity1}"/>
<input type="hidden" id="act2" value="${sessionScope.activity2}"/>
```

Javascript:

```
 $('#act1').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == '1'){
            $('#actDiv1').css('background-color', 'green');
        }else{
            $('#actDiv1').css('background-color', 'red');
        }
 });
 $('#act2').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == '1'){
            $('#actDiv2').css('background-color', 'green');
        }else{
            $('#actDiv2').css('background-color', 'red');
        }
 });
```

Once the value of the hidden field contains a value passed from the session attribute, it will automatically perform the script. So meaning, upon passing of the value, call js function immediately.

Greatly appreciate your help, let me know if there are any other clarifications on this.

Comment: I'm not sure but isn't `JSP` variable parsed only once when HTML is parsed? So your change event will never get called

Comment: This won't work. The session variable gets inserted in the hidden field  when HTML is generated, the server will output an HTML file with those values already populated. No change event will be fired, as your hidden inputs are not changed client-side.

Comment: `session` always remains at server end. And your JS/web page gets executed at client end. Now JSP engine compiles your JSP and sends back the html response to the client browser. So code like `${sessionScope.activity1}` will always gets executed on server side. Whenever html response comes to browser; it will have those hidden fields already populated. So in your JS code you just need to verify their   value.

Answer (score 0):

On page load, input id="act1" will get the value from session. After that, even if the value in session attribute changes, it wont change the value in input id="act1".

Solution : I am assuming you are using some js to change the value in session variable. You can manually set the new value into hidden input and then trigger the change function.

```
$('#hidden_input').val('new_value').trigger('change');
```